# Background video breaking fixed-position element

Tags: css, video, background, position, fixed

I have a full width video background running on a page, its container is absolutely positioned (and needs to be) and this seems to be breaking a fixed position element (an aside) elsewhere on the page.

When I remove the absolute positioning of the video container the aside is fixed as normal. Otherwise the fixed positioning doesn't work.

Here is the page with relevant elements isolated: http://xnthony.com/html/video_fixed.html

I've tested this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of what you want to achieve and what is breaking. As here all is working fine.

Comment: agree, I have no idea what he really wants

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i had no position problems with this plugin: http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Comment: But did you have positioning problems _without_ the plugin? The OP's page works fine here.

Comment: No i had not, but i watched your site again...(i watched it for 2 mins) there are no problems with positioning everything works fine!